Требуется помощь в создании файловой сисетмы
Написал простую операционную систему на Си и NASM
Застрял на моменте создания файловой системы
Вот так сейчас выглядит прототип файловой системы:
void init_file_system() {
    memset(file_table, 0, sizeof(file_table)); // Обнуляем таблицу файлов
    memset(disk, 0, sizeof(disk)); // Обнуляем "диск"
}

int write_block(int block_number, const char* data, int size) {
    if (block_number < 0 || block_number >= MAX_BLOCKS || size > BLOCK_SIZE) {
        return -1; // Ошибка: неверный номер блока или размер
    }
    memcpy(disk[block_number], data, size); // Копируем данные в блок
    return 0; // Успех
}

int read_block(int block_number, char* buffer, int size) {
    if (block_number < 0 || block_number >= MAX_BLOCKS || size > BLOCK_SIZE) {
        return -1; // Ошибка: неверный номер блока или размер
    }
    memcpy(buffer, disk[block_number], size); // Копируем данные в буфер
    return 0; // Успех
}

int create_file(const char* filename, const char* data, int size) {
    if (file_count >= MAX_FILES) return -1; // Превышено максимальное количество файлов

    // Найти первый свободный блок
    int start_block = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BLOCKS; i++) {
        if (strlen(disk[i]) == 0) { // Если блок пустой
            start_block = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (start_block == -1) return -1; // Не найден свободный блок

    // Записать данные в блок
    write_block(start_block, data, size);

    // Сохранить метаданные файла
    strcpy(file_table[file_count].filename, filename);
    file_table[file_count].start_block = start_block;
    file_table[file_count].size = size;
    file_count++;

    return 0; // Успех
}

int read_file(const char* filename, char* buffer) {
    for (int i = 0; i < file_count; i++) {
        if (strcmp(file_table[i].filename, filename) == 0) {
            read_block(file_table[i].start_block, buffer, file_table[i].size);
            return file_table[i].size; // Возвращаем размер файла
        }
    }
    return -1; // Файл не найден
}

bool ends_with(const char *str, const char *suffix) {
    size_t lenstr = strlen(str);
    size_t lensuff = strlen(suffix);
    if (lensuff > lenstr) return false;
    return strcmp(str + lenstr - lensuff, suffix) == 0;
}

void create_file_command() {
    char filename[32];
    char data[BLOCK_SIZE];

    print("Enter filename: ");
    input(filename, sizeof(filename));

    // Проверяем, заканчивается ли имя файла на ".ram"
    if (!ends_with(filename, ".ram")) {
        print("Error: Filename must end with '.ram'\n");
        return;
    }

    print("Enter data to write to file: ");
    input(data, sizeof(data));

    if (create_file(filename, data, strlen(data)) == 0) {
        print("File created successfully.\n");
    } else {
        print("Error creating file.\n");
    }
}

void delete_file_command() {
    char filename[32];
    print("Enter filename to delete: ");
    input(filename, sizeof(filename));

    for (int i = 0; i < file_count; i++) {
        if (strcmp(file_table[i].filename, filename) == 0) {
            // Сдвигаем все файлы в таблице, чтобы удалить текущий
            for (int j = i; j < file_count - 1; j++) {
                file_table[j] = file_table[j + 1];
            }
            file_count--;
            print("File deleted successfully.\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    print("File not found.\n");
}

void read_file_command() {
    char filename[32];
    char buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];

    print("Enter filename to read: ");
    input(filename, sizeof(filename));

    int size = read_file(filename, buffer);
    if (size > 0) {
        buffer[size] = '\0'; // Завершаем строку
        print("File content: ");
        print(buffer);
        print("\n");
    } else {
        print("File not found!\n");
    }
}

void list_files(void) {
    color(COLOR_GREEN);
    print("\nFILES");
    kprint_newline();
    
    if (file_count == 0) {
        print("No files found.\n");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < file_count; i++) {
            print(file_table[i].filename);
            print("\n");
        }
    }
    kprint_newline();
}

То есть пока файл не создаётся физически на диске
Пробовал использовать прерывания для создания физического файла,
но ОС просто не включалась
ОС 32 битная

как задать хороший вопрос

Что за ОС? Можно конкретнее? Контекст вообще не ясен.

Как еще писал Ф. Брукс в своем "Мифический человеко-месяц" -- "... покажите мне свои блок-схемы и я останусь в неведении, покажите мне свои таблицы и блок-схемы мне уже не понадобятся" (под таблицами подразумевайте структуры данных, а под блок-схемами ваш код в вопросе) / (второе -- каким образом связать ваши жалобы на прерывания и ОС не включается с данным в тексте вопроса кодом?) (и наконец, третье -- какой процессор, плату и проч. оборудование используете? Как делаете начальную загрузку?)

Возьмите да и включите в состав своей ОС всего три файла: io.sys, msdos.sys, command.com (из MS DOS 6.22) и сэкономите ну просто кучу времени. Там уже ж всё это есть. Ну, это как модуль подключить или библиотеку какую. Все так  делают. Лейбу, понятно, можно переклеить, это самое быстрое.
